# About changing state from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Say, I have two view controller A and B

in B, I would  like to change the state of A

Using iOS, I have two ways to do this

Method1:

in B, call A.change()

Methed2:

Using NotificationCenter

which way is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods have their own purpose. Depending on your situation, you'll decide which method you need to implement.

---

Method 1:

It works like a 1-to-1 relation. Only one object is accessed. For example, change a property or call a method of an object.

Method 2:

It works like a 1-to-many relation. It broadcast the event and everyone who is listening to that event will be notified. For example `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, any number of objects can start listening to those notifications and when those event occur, all those objects will be notified simultaneously.

---

In your situation, I suggest, make a `delegate`. Assign `B.delegate = A`. Call

```
[B.delegate performSelector:@selector(change)];
```